# SetCursor() in java doesn't change the cursor

Tags: java, swing, button, jtextpane, mouse-cursor

Well, I created a custom jbutton and a custom jtextpane. Originally they were placed on a panel and setCursor() worked perfectly. But later, I had to add a JScrollPane that contains the original panel. Since I did that, when I place the mouse on the button or the textpane, the cursor doesn't change, it is still an arrow. I tried adding mouse listener events for both the button and the textpane, but it doesn't work either.

```
public class CreacionPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static JPanel textfields = new JPanel();
    static JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    static JPanel panelNombres;

    public CreacionPrincipal() {
       initComponents();

       panelNombres = new JPanel();
       //jscrollPane
       panelNombres.add(scrollPane);
       scrollPane.setViewportView(textfields);
       textfields.setLayout(null);
       scrollPane.setBounds(40, 190, 440, 230);
       scrollPane.setBorder(null);
       textfields.setBackground(Color.black);
       textfields.setBorder(null);

       CustomButton boton1 = new CustomButton(posYBoton);
       CustomTextPane campo1 = new CustomTextPane(posYPanel);
       CustomTextPane NombrePrincipal = new CustomTextPane();
    }
}

public class CustomButton extends JButton{

   public CustomButtom (int posY) {
      
      boton = new JButton("+");
      boton.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
      boton.setBounds(390, posY, 30, 30);
      boton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
      boton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Cascadia Mono", 1, 20));
      boton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
      boton.setFocusPainted(false);
      boton.setOpaque(false);
      boton.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255)));
      boton.setVisible(true);
      boton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
      boton.addMouseListener(mouse);
      textfields.add(boton);

      MouseListener mouse = new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                posYPanel = posYPanel + 60;
                posYBoton = posYBoton + 60;
                CustomTextPane panel = new CustomTextPane(posYPanel);
                boton.setBounds(390, posYBoton, 30, 30);  

                textfields.add(panel);
            }
        };
   }
}

public class CustsomTextPane extends JTextPane {
   JTextPane areaOpcional;
   JTextPane nombrePrincipal;
    
    public CustomTextPane(int PosY) {
        areaOpcional = new JTextPane();
        areaOpcional.setVisible(true);
        areaOpcional.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        areaOpcional.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 179, 0));
        areaOpcional.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 24));
        areaOpcional.setBorder(null);
        areaOpcional.setCaretColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        areaOpcional.setBounds(0, PosY, 380, 40);
        areaOpcional.setSelectedTextColor(new java.awt.Color(187,187,187));
        areaOpcional.setSelectionColor(new java.awt.Color(75,110,175));
        areaOpcional.setFocusable(true);
        areaOpcional.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));
        areaOpcional.setEditable(true);
        areaOpcional.setOpaque(true);
        areaOpcional.setEnabled(true);
        textfields.add(areaOpcional);
        textfields.repaint();
        textfields.revalidate();
        areaOpcional.repaint();
        areaOpcional.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your CustomTextPane class is all wrong. 1) When you extend a class don't create an instance of that class. 2) Don't create any other components in the class. All your class should do is change the functionality/properties of the the text pane. Other issue: 1) don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 2) Don't use static variables. This also indicates poor design.  3) Don't add a MouseListener to a JButton. Instead use an ActionListener to handle clicking the button.

Comment: Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. The demo code will show you how to better structure your code and use Swing features.